# Limit thread with partitioner Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My Spring batch application consumes too many resources (+4 go Ram).

When I look at the jvm, the application creates 10 threads.

- I use the partitioner to process file by file without scheduler
- jobExecutionListener is used to stop the batch at the end of execution

  ```
  @Bean
  public Job mainJob() throws IOException {
  SimpleJobBuilder mainJob = this.jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")
              .start(previousStep())    
              .next(partitionStep())
              .next(finalStep())
              .listener(jobExecutionListener(taskExecutor()));;
      return mainJob.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step partitionStep() throws IOException {
      Step mainStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("mainStep")
              .<InOut, InOut>chunk(1)
              .reader(ResourceReader())
              .processor(processor())
              .writer(itemWriter())
              .build();

      return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
              .partitioner(mainStep)
              .partitioner("mainStep", partitioner())
              .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
      ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
      taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
      taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1);
      taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyBatch-");
      taskExecutor.initialize();

      return taskExecutor;
  }

  //This jobExecutionListener stop the batch
  @Bean
  public JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") 
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor) {
      return new JobExecutionListener() {
          private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = executor;
          @Override
          public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
          }

          @Override
          public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
              taskExecutor.shutdown();
              System.exit(0);
          }
      };
  }

  @Bean
  public Partitioner partitioner() {
      MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
      ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new 
      PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

      try {
          partitioner.setResources(patternResolver.getResources(FILE + 
      configProperties.getIn()+ "/*.xml"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.",e);
      }
      partitioner.setKeyName("file");
      return partitioner;
  }
  ```

How can I apply my application in monothread ? The taskexecutor doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app creates 10 threads but those are not necessarily Spring Batch threads. According to your config, only one thread with prefix `MyBatch-` should be created.

Moreover, you declared a task executor as a bean but you did not set it on the partitioned step. Your `partitionStep` should be something like:

```
@Bean
public Step partitionStep() throws IOException {
   Step mainStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("mainStep")
        .<InOut, InOut>chunk(1)
        .reader(ResourceReader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(itemWriter())
        .build();

   return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
        .step(mainStep) // instead of .partitioner(mainStep)
        .partitioner("mainStep", partitioner())
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
}
```

> How can I apply my application in monothread ? The taskexecutor doesn't work.

After setting the task executor on the partitioned step, you should see this step being executed by the sole thread as defined in your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. However, I don't see the benefit of using a single thread for a partitioned step, because the usual goal for such a setup is to process partitions in parallel (either locally with multiple threads or remotely with multiple worker JVMs).

As a side note, it's good that you shutdown the task executor with a Job listener in `afterJob`, but don't `System.exit`. You need to let the JVM shutdown gracefully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, I forgot the .listener(jobExecutionListener(taskExecutor ())) in the main job to call the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor (in my code). I edited my code.

I tested your method but it doesn't work, the batch always uses 4g of ram.
I see my thread (MyBatch-) in the jvm but it's too fast to be monothread.

I'm using the system.exit to close the window after running.

Comment: My answer does not address memory consumption (and it won't improve it). Your question was about threading. With my answer, your partitioned step should use 1 thread (the one from the thread pool). For memory consumption, you need to specify more details about your app in the question: how much data it loads in memory, how many steps are run in parallel, etc.