# Unable to limit the parallelism using ThreadPoolExecutor with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Here's my configuration:

```
    @StepScope
    @Bean(name = "mySlaveStep")
    public Step mySlaveStep(
            @Qualifier(value = "myReader") ItemReader reader,
            @Qualifier(value = "myWriter") ItemWriter writer,
            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MySlaveStep")
                .<SomeObject, SomeObject>chunk(1000)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myStep")
    public Step myStep(
            @Qualifier(value = "myPartitioner") Partitioner partitioner, // with @StepScope
            @Qualifier(value = "myExecutor") TaskExecutor executor, // With/without @StepScope
            @Qualifier(value = "myStep") Step step, // With @StepScope
            StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("MyStep")
                .partitioner("MyPartition", partitioner)
                .taskExecutor(executor)
                .step(step)
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope // With or without
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        return executor;
    }
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.mySlaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

So I assume this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395359/spring-batch-error-no-context-holder-available-for-step-scope-when-using-thread). Removing/adding `@StepScope` from `TaskExecutor` bean does not change the outcome, however, removing `TaskExecutor` altogether resolves the issue. I'm only trying to limit the number of parallel partitions being handled as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020199/limit-thread-with-partitioner-spring-batch). How do I go about it?

Comment: I added an answer about bean scopes. But in order to correctly answer the question about  limiting the parallelism using a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, I need to know which implementation of `PartitionHandler` you are using. Is it the `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler`? This is key to answer that question, but is not mentioned in the code you shared.

Comment: I'm not using a specific `PartitionHandler`, not configuring it at all. The whole configuration is as in the question. So do I use `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` and pass my `taskExecutor()` to it?

Comment: ok, so by default you will get a `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` from the builder, configured with your task executor. With that in place, any limit on the number of threads you set on the task executor should be applied/respected by the partitioned step as expected. I see you accepted the answer. Glad it helped!

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I understand, but the real issue was related to autowiring, which is your actual answer, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will address the scope of the task executor. The task executor should not be "SpringBatch-scoped" (job-scoped or step-scoped) or even scoped at all (IMO the default singleton scope is the correct scope of such a compnent for most use cases). Spring Batch does not create or manage threads, it delegates that to task executors in different parts of the framework. Therefore, such a component should not be impacted by any scope of Spring Batch and should not impact the behaviour of a Spring Batch job by any mean. If this is the case, that would be a bug in Spring Batch.

Now let me address the scope of a step. A step in Spring Batch cannot be step-scoped. That does not make sense. Marking the step as step-scoped means do not create that step bean until the job enclosing it is running (ie at runtime). But, at that time, the step was not configured yet. A batch artefact of a step (reader, writer, listener, tasklet, partitioner, etc) can be step-scoped though, but not the step itself. There is a note about that in the reference documentation here: [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding). Removing the step scope on `mySlaveStep` should fix your issue.

While I see valid use cases for step components to be scoped (to use late-binding for instance), I do not see any valid use case to scope the step itself.

Comment: Removing `@StepScope` from `mySlaveStep`, making `TaskExecutor` not step scoped and using `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` resolved the issue.